# Need to slow rectangle movement

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, pong

I am having a problem with threading. I am trying to recreate pong where there are 2 Action Listeners for 2 players. The 2 paddles move at the speed that I want them to move at. However, the "ball"(Rectangle object with an oval painted over it) is moving way too fast. I've tried slowing it down using a second thread in the Ball class, but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated. 
Here's my code:

```
public class BattleBallz extends JFrame implements Runnable {
AL keyListen1 = new AL();
AL2 keyListen2 = new AL2();
Image dbi;
Graphics dbg;

int x1,x2;
int ballX, ballY, direction;
Ball b1;

public BattleBallz(){
    setTitle("Battle Ballz");
    setSize(350, 400);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addKeyListener(keyListen1);
    addKeyListener(keyListen2);
    x1 = 150;
    x2 = 150;
    int direction = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((2 - 0) + 1));
    b1 = new Ball(direction);
    Thread b = new Thread(b1);
    b.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    dbi = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbi.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbi, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle(x1,375,60,10);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(x1, 375, 60, 10);
    Rectangle p2 = new Rectangle(x2,45,60,10);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x2,45,60,10);

    b1.paintComponent(g, p1, p2);

    repaint();
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true){
            move();
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

public void move(){
    x1 += keyListen1.getXdirection();
    x2 += keyListen2.getXdirection();

    if (x1<=0){
        x1 =0;
    }
    if (x1>=305){
        x1 = 305;
    }
    if (x2<=0){
        x2=0;
    }
    if (x2>=305){
        x2=305;
    }
}
}

public class Ball extends JPanel implements Runnable {

boolean up,down,right,left;
int x = 150, y = 150 ;

public Ball(int direction){
    if(direction ==1){
        down = true;
    }
    if (direction ==0){
        up = true;
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g, Rectangle p1, Rectangle p2){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    if(down){
        y++;
        Rectangle ball = new Rectangle(x,y,49,49);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        if (y>=385 || ball.intersects(p1)){
            down = false;
            up = true;
        }
    }
    if (up){
        y--;
        Rectangle ball = new Rectangle(x,y,49,49);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        if (y<=10 || ball.intersects(p2)){
            up = false;
            down = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        while (true){
            Thread.sleep(30);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Never asked a question here before. Trying to figure out how to post my Ball class.

Comment: The other code is rather irrelevant, we probably only need the run method from the Ball class and any method that calls.

Comment: *"Never asked a question here before."*  Speaking of which:  Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Answer (score 3):

1. use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of plain `Thread`, you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), code posted to block `Event Dispatch Thread`, locked by `Thread.sleep`, endless block
2. use `paintComponent` but put there `JPanel`, 1st. code line inside should be `super.paintComponent`, otherwise paint is cumulated, override `getPreferredSize` for `JPanel`
3. use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: search in posts tagged by paintComponent, part of them contains (in answers) very good code about my points